# I got some errors when I pip install bfieldtools

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip

```
PS C:\Python\source> pip install bfieldtools
Collecting bfieldtools
  Using cached bfieldtools-0.9.13.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting trimesh
  Using cached trimesh-3.16.4-py3-none-any.whl (663 kB)
Collecting mayavi
  Using cached mayavi-4.8.1.tar.gz (20.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\billlin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe' 'C:\Users\billlin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-gje45057\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\billlin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-32lpxcys\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- oldest-supported-numpy setuptools vtk wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (8 lines):
  Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
    Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.8.16-py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-65.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: none)      
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk
  WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\billlin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Could someone please help me ? I list the log as above. I was using version 22.3.1 and someone asked me to use it back to the previous version of pip for another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Install below vtx
by entering following command

```
pip install vtk==9.2.2
```

https://pypi.org/project/vtk/

Comment: I got the message as below, 

PS C:\Python\source> pip install vtk==9.2.2 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk==9.2.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk==9.2.2
PS C:\Python\source>

Comment: Can you provide Python version and Pip version. OS

Comment: >& C:/Users/billlin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python --version
Python 3.11.0

Comment: >& C:/Users/billlin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python --version
Python 3.11.0                                                                                                                  > pip install vtk==9.2.2   (pip version, 21.3.1)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk==9.2.2 (from versions: none)                                                                                                                    ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk==9.2.2

Comment: > pip install vtk==9.2.2  (pip version, 22.3.1)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk==9.2.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk==9.2.2

Comment: Python 11 not supporting this use Python3.10 version.

Comment: I marked #from bfieldtools.utils import cylinder_points as comment and inserted the whole content of utils.py, and marked #from bfieldtools.line_magnetics import magnetic_field as comment and inserted the whole content of line_magnetics.py. I also marked #from .integrals import omega as comment. andＩ added one statement in the end, plt.show(). Finally it works well.